How to Reuse Components, Utilities, and Configuration Across Multiple Next.js Applications?
I am currently working on two Next.js applications that share a similar design, structure, and configuration, but also have some distinct differences.
In Nuxt.js, there is a concept of layers that allows you to share code, configuration, and components across multiple projects efficiently.
Is there an equivalent concept in Next.js? If not, what are the best practices for sharing and reusing components, utilities, and configuration between multiple Next.js applications?

I think a monorepo could be a good fit for what you describe. You might wanna take a look at Turborepo https://turbo.build/repo/docs, it's from the creators on Next.js.
